# How to go live from Sandbox to Live with Paypal in Java?

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I just need your help on this , i am using Paypal integration in my website using java Language , here i am using Express Checkout Service and Rest API Calls for using Direct Credit card payments , now I have created sandbox accounts and tested them. Its working really good with proper responses .

Now For getting live payments we have a business merchant account in US and we have linked that Bank to our Paypal account , and when i am providing credentials for that Business account for REST API Transactions it is throwing an Error

Error code : `401 with response : Server returned HTTP response code: 401`

And the code Causing this error is :

Map sdkConfig = new HashMap();
        sdkConfig.put("mode", "live");

```
    CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
    creditCard.setType("visa");
    creditCard.setNumber("4446283280247004");
    creditCard.setExpireMonth(11);
    creditCard.setExpireYear(2018);
    creditCard.setFirstName("Joe Shopper");

    creditCard.setCvv2("177");
    Details details = new Details();
    details.setShipping("0");
    details.setSubtotal("0.01");
    details.setTax("0");


    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency("USD");
    amount.setTotal("0.01");
    amount.setDetails(details);
   int random = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
    System.out.println(random);
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setAmount(amount);
    transaction.setDescription("This is the payment transaction description.");


    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    transactions.add(transaction);
    FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
    fundingInstrument.setCreditCard(creditCard);


    List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstrumentList = new ArrayList<FundingInstrument>();
    fundingInstrumentList.add(fundingInstrument);
    Payer payer = new Payer();
    payer.setFundingInstruments(fundingInstrumentList);
    payer.setPaymentMethod("credit_card");
    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.setIntent("Sale");
    payment.setPayer(payer);
    payment.setTransactions(transactions);

    try {
        String accessToken = GenerateAccessToken.getAccessToken();
       APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        apiContext.setConfigurationMap(sdkConfig);
       Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);
     System.out.println(Payment.getLastResponse());


        List<Transaction> trans = createdPayment.getTransactions();


    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Kindly Please tell me what should i have to do to resolve this issue for making smooth transactions and transferring real payments , and if is there anything i have to do in my Paypal account settings for making live , Please tell me that too.

Comment: Can you post the codes that causes this error...

Comment: Hi Xlander i have Edited my question and put my code into it , which is causing error

Comment: Sounds like you must not be hitting the correct API endpoint..??